# R merge strange behavior

Tags: r, function, merge

Doing join of 2 data.frame with `merge` function I have found that the argument `sort` of it don't change nothing. Example:

```
id_df <- structure(list(id = c("click", "event", "funnel", "impression", 
                               "tracker", "visibility"), 
                        id_Havas = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6")), 
                   .Names = c("id", "my_id"), class = "data.frame", 
                   row.names = c(NA, -6L))

my_df <- data.frame("id" = c("click", "click", "impression", "visibility", "click"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Results:

```
my_df

# id
# 1      click
# 2      click
# 3 impression
# 4 visibility
# 5      click

merge(my_df, id_df, by = "id", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
# id my_id
# 1      click    a1
# 2      click    a1
# 3      click    a1
# 4 impression    a4
# 5 visibility    a6

merge(my_df, id_df, by = "id", all.x = TRUE, sort = TRUE)
# id my_id
# 1      click    a1
# 2      click    a1
# 3      click    a1
# 4 impression    a4
# 5 visibility    a6
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: I have to do left join, so using `all.x = T`. The problem is that I want to maintain an orden of my_df after merge

Comment: oh ok. The way the question was asked I thought you did want the sorting, hence my remark that it was already sorted. What about using `match` instead (see my answer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the original order, you can use `match`:

```
my_df$my_id <- id_df$my_id[match(my_df$id, id_df$id)]
my_df
#          id my_id
#1      click    a1
#2      click    a1
#3 impression    a4
#4 visibility    a6
#5      click    a1
```

***benchmark comparision between `merge` and `match` for your specific case, considering 60000 different ids and 100000 rows for `my_df`:***

```
f_merge <- function(){merge(my_df, id_df, by = "id", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)}
f_match <- function(){my_df$my_id <- id_df$my_id[match(my_df$id, id_df$id)]}
microbenchmark(f_match(), f_merge(), unit="relative")
 #     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 #f_match()  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000 1.000000   100  a 
 #f_merge() 41.16602 46.42379 26.62328 47.59711 17.28836 7.176999   100   b
```

**How does argument `sort` in `merge` works:**

From `?merge`, "value" section, you can read:

> The rows are by default lexicographically sorted on the common columns, but for sort = FALSE are in an unspecified order.

So all common names are "put together" but the unique names are not sorted if `sort=FALSE`.

***Example:***

```
my_df <- data.frame("id" = c("impression", "click", "click", "impression", "visibility", "click"), stringsAsFactors = F)

merge(my_df, id_df, by = "id", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
#          id my_id
#1 impression    a4
#2 impression    a4
#3      click    a1
#4      click    a1
#5      click    a1
#6 visibility    a6

merge(my_df, id_df, by = "id", all.x = TRUE, sort = TRUE)
#          id my_id
#1      click    a1
#2      click    a1
#3      click    a1
#4 impression    a4
#5 impression    a4
#6 visibility    a6
```

Comment: that's a nice way to solve the problem of the example. But imagine you want to merge larger tables,  with much more columns.

Comment: you can still use `match`, just keep the columns, eg `my_df <- data.frame(my.df, id_df[match(my_df$id, id_df$id), ])`

Comment: it is interesting... and what is the difference between this method and merge function? It terms of efficiency

Comment: @AndriyTkach, here `merge` and `match` works in a similar way but only because you are doing only left join and on only one common column. In term of efficiency, in a case like yours with data.frame of 100000 lines for `my_df` and 60000 ids, `match` is far more efficient (almost 50 times more efficient than `merge`), see my edit.

Comment: @GathG, very interesting results and explanation, thank you for that. But I still wondering how does that argument `sort` in `merge` works...

Comment: @AndriyTkach, see the end of my answer for an explanation

Comment: @GathG, now I see, wondering why it "puts together". Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndriyTkach, probably for reason of efficiency in the "merge process". you're welcome, never notices the sort argument before, can be useful, and so now I know better this function thanks to you ;-)